# Move cursor to end of line in vim (to delete last word)

Tags: vim, editor

I usually type the command `db` to remove one word backwards in Vim. Doing this at the end of a line without whitespace leaves the last character of the word since the cursor starts removing from the second last character.

I can press `b` followed by `de` instead, but I find this confusing sometimes when doing it many times in a row, leading to unneccesary mistakes. I was hoping there was a way to go to the end of the line and remove the last word backwards.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you could try `:nnoremap db dbx` or `:nnoremap db bde`.  Might come with some side-effects that you don't like, though.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons , Not a bad idea. Remapping to `bde` wouldn't affect much functionality (only when removing part of a word I think). `dbx` would however overwrite the functionality of using `db` normally by always removing an extra whitespace or occasionally an extra character, which makes it worse to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

- use a mapping like this:

  ```
  :nnoremap <silent> db :exe 'norm!' (col('.')==col('$')-1 ? 'daw' : 'db')<cr>
  ```
- alternatively, you can do `:set ve=onemore` which allows you to go one
  char past the end of line, then once your cursor is past the end (see command `g$`), simply use `db`.

**EDIT** (explanations)

- `:exe` executes the string formed by its arguments as a command.
  So if the cursor is at the end of line (`col('.')==col('$')-1`),
  it will execute:

  ```
  :norm! daw
  ```

  otherwise it will execute:

  ```
  :norm! db
  ```
- `:norm` lets you run normal commands in the command line. For example if you're already in
  normal mode, typing `:norm db` + <kbd>return</kbd> will do the same as just typing `db`.
  It's useful inside commands. The `!` prevents mappings to be used in the `:norm` commands.
  See `:h :norm`.
- `<silent>` makes a mapping silent: without it you would see
  `:exe 'norm!' (col('.')==col('$')-1 ?  'daw' : 'db')` in the bottom of the
  screen.
  See `:h <silent>`.
- `<cr>` is the key code for the return key. You can put this kind of codes inside mappings.
  In this case, `<cr>` will validate the command just entered in the mapping.
  See `:h keycodes` for details.

Comment: This seems like a solution very specific to my problem as it is stated, and interesting, but I am not sure if I understand it. Could you explain how that remapping works and specifically what `<silent>`, `exe 'norm!'` and `<cr>` does? I have never used remaps before and it is difficult for me to find all details in the documentation.

Comment: Great explanation! I feel that this answered my question perfectly, while the answer by @dlmeetei is probably a better way to go about it.

Comment: I meant to say @DJMcMayhem before, since it is better. But they are the same answers I guess.

Comment: While this answer is the specific answer to your question (and with that of course a valid answer), it is not the answer you need. I would strongly recommend using DJ's solution!

Comment: I just realized that this does not solve the problem with whitespace at the end of a sentence. Mapping to `bd$` or `bdaw` at line-end instead of `daw` would solve this, right?

Answer (score 8):

You should train yourself to stop using `db` and learn to love text objects instead. This problem happens even if you're not at the end of a line.

```
foo bar baz
      ^
```

and then <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> will give

```
foo r bax
    ^
```

Instead of using `db` or `de` or even `dw`, train yourself to use `diw` and `daw`. This might take some getting used to, but down the road it will become natural and be way more convenient to use. And once the text objects become natural to you, you can then start using other commands (`'c'` or `'y'`, etc.) or even other text objects. (I can't even count how many times I've used `dap` or `ci(`)

For a short explanation of what these do, think of `diw` as `(d)elete (i)nside this (w)ord` and `daw` as `(d)elete (a)round this (w)ord` or `(d)elete (a) (w)ord`. For a more concrete example:

```
foo bar baz
          ^
```

typing `diw` gives

```
foo bar 
       ^
(note the leading space)
```

But

```
foo bar baz
          ^
```

typing `daw` gives

```
foo bar
      ^
```

And as long as your cursor is over the same word, these will still do the same thing. So if we moved the cursor back to the 'a' or the 'b', you'll get the exact same results. [This blog](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/10/17/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/) goes into more depth on text objects.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$diw
```

$ - takes you to last character of the line
d - as you know is for delete
i - implies from inside. Read more on other powerful text objects `:help text-objects`
w - word

If you are not habituated using `text-objects`, start using. You will love it